# Linq on a null value

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I am trying to get value of dcs.Agent.AgentAlive (boolean) but I am unable to do so, can someone suggest way around. I think dcs.Agent.AgentAlive is null in some cases..

```
var dc = (from dcs in DataCollectionStatuses
select new { 
     dcs.Frequency, ha= dcs.Agent??dcs.Agent
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Constructing or initializing instances of the type <>f__AnonymousType1`2 System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],DynamicOps.ManagementModel.Agent] with the expression (dcs.Agent ?? dcs.Agent) is not supported.

Comment: What does `dcs.Agent ?? dcs.Agent` even mean? It's the same as just writing `dcs.Agent`.

Comment: I think the exception you give might be fixed by adding changing `DataCollectionStatuses` to `DataCollectionStatuses.AsEnumerable()` but that won't help you with the `AgentAlive` malarkey.

Comment: DataCOllectionStatuses has a object Agent, which has a property AgentAlive which i am trying to include in linq query.

I am a scriptor, with basic linq knowledge. Appreicate you kind help.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to know if the agent is alive correct?
If agent is null i assume he isn't.
Then you just need the very usefull Ternary Operator ?:

```
var dc = (from dcs in DataCollectionStatuses
          select new { 
                       dcs.Frequency,
                       IsAgentAlive = dcs.Agent!=null ? dcs.Agent.AgentAlive:false
                     }
         ).FirstOrDefault();
```

for more info
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx